# how to get associative array value in php?

Tags: php

I have an associative array in php that looks like this

```
incSched={"62":"10878","63":"10878","64":"10878","65":"10878","66":"28416","67":"28416","68":"28416","69":"28416","70":"28416"}
```

How do I access the value for "62"?

I've tried

```
$amt = $incSched[$j];
$amt = $incSched["$j"];
$amt = $incSched[strval($j)];
```

they all return an empty string.

Here is the full loop so you can see what $j is:

```
$startAge = 53;
for ($i=0; $i<count($incTableIds); $i++) {
    $tableId = $incTableIds[$i];
    for ($j=$startAge; $j<101; $j++) {
        $incSched = $incomeSchedules[$tableId];
        echo "incSched=" .json_encode($incSched) ."<br>";
        $amt = $incSched["$j"];
        if ($amt == "") $amt = 0;
        if ($j>$startAge) $amt = $incSchedules[$tableId][$j-1]; //use previous value
        echo "Income: tableId=$tableId, age=$j, amt=$amt<br>";
        $incSchedules[$tableId][$j] = $amt;
    }
}
```

Here is the output when the loop hits 62

```
Income: tableId=1, age=62, amt=0
```

amt should be 10878, not 0.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your logic is strange: `if ($j>$startAge) $amt = $incSchedules[$tableId][$j-1];` - this if is true when $j == 62, so in this case you set `$amt` to the last value which is `0` (conveniently set by the last iteration $j == 61).

Comment: Yes you are right.  Stupid me!  I changed it to    if ($amt == "") {
    $amt = 0;
    if ($j>$startAge) $amt = $incSchedules[$tableId][$j-1]; //use previous value
   } and now it is working fine.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the JSON Format but without the quotes. In order to decode the JSON format, you'll have to convert your value into a JSON string. Try this below code:

```
// $incSched = '[{"62":"10878"},{"63":"10878"},{"64":"10878"},{"65":"10878"},{"66":"28416"},{"67":"28416"},{"68":"28416"},{"69":"28416"},{"70":"28416"}]';
$incSched = '{"62":"10878","63":"10878","64":"10878","65":"10878","66":"28416","67":"28416","68":"28416","69":"28416","70":"28416"}';
$incSched = json_decode($incSched, true);

foreach ($incSched as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . '=>'. $value . '<br />';
}
```

In the above, I have given you both the valid formats of JSON.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm only doing the json_encode to view the data.  by decoding your just putting it back the way it already is.

Comment: can you tell me what value you are getting after this `$incSched = $incomeSchedules[$tableId];`. Can you post what you are getting in `$incSched` after the above statement just before encoding ?

Comment: echo "incSched=" .$incSched ."<br>";  Output is incSched=Array

Comment: You cannot print an array using echo. Try with print_r function.